# Gauge-fixing conditions in Einstein-Cartan gravity

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, gauge-theory, gauge

What are the gauge-fixing conditions one needs to impose on the tetrad one-form $e^a$ and the spin-connection one-form $\omega^{ab}$ while working in the Einstein-Cartan formalism where both are independent objects? I am more interested in the case of 4D gravity.

Comment: Could you clarify what you're looking for/give some context? There are few circumstances in which one *needs* to fix a gauge...

Comment: @RichardMyers The context is path integrals in 4D gravity. To do the path integral correctly I need a gauge-fixing condition to get the right Fadeev-Popov determinant.

Comment: The entire point of the FP procedure is that it doesn't matter how you gauge-fix...

Comment: @RichardMyers Yes but we need one gauge-fixing condition to determine the FD determinant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Analogous to Equation 3.3 of this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/gr-qc/9406006.pdf, one can propose the following gauge conditions in all dimensions $D > 3$

$$*D* e^a = *[d*\omega^{ab}+(\omega \wedge *\omega)^{ab}] = 0$$